# How can I deploy code to production when I am running celery, redis, django with docker compose?

Tags: django, docker-compose, deployment, celery

I am running celery, Redis, Django, and flower containers with docker compose. The docker-compose.yml file is similar to [this tutorial](https://testdriven.io/courses/django-celery/docker/). The whole app can run very well.

The problem is when I change the code and deploy it to production. I found that the code was often not updated and this caused errors. For example, I try to change the celery task code or add new tasks. The updated tasks cannot be deployed

From [restarting the workers](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#stopping-the-worker), I tried to run the commands:

```
celery multi start 1 -A proj -l INFO -c4 --pidfile=/var/run/celery/%n.pid
celery multi restart 1 --pidfile=/var/run/celery/%n.pid

kill -HUP $pid
```

But the task is not updated after my testing. The task is still loading the old code. How can I deploy code to production? Should I restart the container with?

```
docker-compose restart celery
```

From [the celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#restarting-the-worker), it says that:
For production deployments you should be using init-scripts or a process supervision system (see Daemonization).

The [Daemonization](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#daemonizing) is completely not related to docker. I don't understand how Daemonization is related to deployment with docker / docker compose. Actually I don't understand why Daemonization is related to deployment from the official docs.

Comment: Hi @BennyChan, please did you later find a solution for this?

Comment: I just send a kill signal to celery - docker-compose kill -s HUP celery